# What do you call this? Function that sets parameters of other function as fixed

Tags: functional-programming

When I took a class on function programming at university a few years back, we learned about this programming pattern, where you have a function that takes X arguments, and then you define another function that only takes X-1 arguments and sets the last one as constant.

Example (python):

```
createTensor = lambda x,y,z: [[[0 for _ in range(x)] for _ in range(y)] for _ in range(z)]
createMatrix = lambda x,y: createTensor(x,y,1)
createVector = lambda x: createMatrix(x,1)
```

Would be fun to hear what such a function would be called.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application

Comment: Thanks! Now that you pointed this out, I think I might have mixed up partial application and curried functions in my head. I think the term I actually remember wasn't "salted" but "curried" (which is related but not exactly what I described above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the answer was in the comments, I'll just post it as a regular answer:

It's called a **partial function application**. The function itself would be called a **partially applied function**.

The concept is related to "currying" (decomposing a function into functions that take only one argument), which I believe is the concept I actually remembered from my classes - and probably the name I had in mind when I posted the question.